# Categorizing (and constructing) a matrix which has a full-rank kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Assume that all matrices/vectors are real valued and

- $N < M$
- $B$ is a $N\times M$ matrix with rank $N$
- $Q$ is a $M \times (M-N)$ matrix.  Figuring out properties/construction of $Q$ is the main goal.
- $u$ is column vector of length $M-N$
- $ \mathbf{0}_p$ is a column vector of $p$ zeros

A key property of $Q$ is that

First, for all $u\in \Bbb R^{M-N}$,
$$
B Q u = \mathbf{0}_N
$$

The matrix $P \equiv B Q$ is a $N \times (M-N)$ matrix.

Is there a named relationship between $Q$ and $B$ in the above (i.e. how is this related to the kernel, nullspace, etc.)  That is, given a $Q$ how would I check if it fulfills this relationship for all $u$.

Furthermore, is there a named relationship between $Q$ and $B$ in the above (i.e., it is not the inverse, but is this related to annihilators?)  If so, is there a way to construct a $Q$ for a given $B$, and is this unique (up to a scaling factor)?

Edit: previous mistakes in the sizes of matrices, and removed the second part of a question.

Comment: $Pu = 0$ for all $u\in\Bbb R^N$ means that $\ker P = \Bbb R^N$ i.e. $P=0$ since $P$ is $N\times N$, not that the rank of $P$ is $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Pu = 0$ for all $u\in\Bbb R^{M-N}$ means that $\ker P = \Bbb R^{M-N}$ i.e. $P=0$. 
Indeed, if $(e_1,...e_{M-N})$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^{M-N}$, then $\forall i$, the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $P$ is $Pe_i = 0$, thus $P$ has only zero columns!

Thus, you want $Q$ such that $BQ = 0$ i.e. such that **each column** $C_i$ **of** $Q$ **belongs to** $\ker B$, i.e. $BC_i = 0,\forall i\in\{1,...,N\}$. Of course, a matrix $B$ satisfying this can't be unique (simply permute the columns or replace one of them by a linear combination of them or...).

Comment: Thanks so much, very helpful. Let me edit the question a little based on the information you have given, if that is OK

Comment: Given your comments on uniqueness, I think I need to add in another condition to make the 2nd question more meaningful.

Comment: So sorry, I realized that I had a mistake in the original formulation of the problem which I didn't notice because of the example $N$ and $M$ sizes I had tested.  The size of $P$ is now $N \times (N-M)$.  I imagine this will change your answer.  I also removed the second part, which I think will be useful as a different question.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't change my answer a lot (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I think this answers this question.  I might post a separate question for the decomposition I mentioned before.